# Difference between mean of the proportions and proportion of the means

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Sorry I'm not sure which channel I should post this question to, but I think it's inherently math related (because a math concept should reflect a *real* objective I guess), thus this post.

Suppose I have historical sales of 2 products (A and B) as follows:

```
product_A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2]
product_B = [3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 4]
hist_total_sales = [4, 7, 12, 13, 15, 6]
```

Using historical total sales, I forecast for future total sales which I can allocate to 2 products using either method

```
method_1 = mean(product_A / hist_total_sales)
forecast_A = method_1 * total_forecast

method_2 = mean(product_A ) / mean(hist_total_sales)
forecast_A = method_2 * total_forecast
```

What is the *intuitive* difference between `method_1` and `method_2`? Which method is logically sound as a basis to allocate the total sales forecast to each product?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you just have two months of data.  The first month you sell $0\ A$s and $10\ B$s.  The second month you sell $1000\ A$s and $0\ B$s.  The first method will forecast you will sell the same number of $A$s and $B$s as they each were $100\%$ of your sales in one month, which averages to $50\%$ for each.  The second will predict $99\%\ A$s because they account for that percentage of your total sales.

I would really want to forecast the sales of $A$s and $B$s separately, then figure out what fraction each is of the total.

Comment: Thank you for your input, @Ross Millikan. I agreed that it would be better to forecast the sales for each product separately (called bottom up approach). The reason I asked the question was because the 2 methods mentioned in the post were presented in a tutorial on forecasting (called top down approach). I wonder why the top down approach was invented and discussed at the first place.

Comment: If you have lots of products and the sales mix doesn't change much anything works.  You could then say it looks like our sales are growing $10\%$ per year, so that becomes your top down estimate.  It is a lot less work.

Comment: You're totally right. But on purely mathematical viewpoint, what is the actual difference between `method_1` and `method_2` (for example, in your special case, it was 99% - 50% = 45%) or that can't be generalised because the members of product sales are arbitrary?

Comment: Method 1 will weight sales on days when the total sales are low much more that method 2.  I chose my numbers to accentuate that.  If the sales don't change much from one day to another the methods will be very close.  I don't think you can say much more than that.  The weighting is the thing to look for in questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for that insight, Ross. Much appreciated.